# VBScript loops in section of sub that does not contain looping code

Tags: windows, vbscript

Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 20H2

---

I am writing a VBScript that handles a print to PDF dialogue window.

**The goal:**

1. Detect that the printer dialogue window is open (using a loop that continuously checks)
2. If/when detected, handle the dialogue (send the filename, send the file path, click "print" to finish)

**The problem:** for some reason, the sub endlessly loops through an If statement. *I don't understand why the code is looping through a section containing no loop code.*

The code basically sends the same keys in a loop over and over again within the dialogue window, never completing the If statement.

As a small aside, I think the sendKeys command I use to close the dialogue is incorrect, but that should not cause an IF statement to loop.

**Code** (go to the section indicated by "#"'s to see where I am having issues):

```
Sub handlePrintDial()

    iSeconds = 20

'================================================================================
' Set time variables
'================================================================================

    tNow = now()
    tFuture = DateAdd("s",iSeconds,tNow)

'================================================================================
' Set other objects
'================================================================================

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    sApp = "Save Print Output As"

    sFileName = "This is a test-" & Year(now()) & Month(now()) & Day(now()) & Hour(now()) & Minute(now()) & Second(now())

'================================================================================
' Loop until window opens or time elapses
'================================================================================

    Do Until Now() > tFuture
        ret = WshShell.AppActivate(sApp)
        If ret = True Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    If ret <> True Then
        MsgBox "Printer window not found. Please try again."
        Exit Sub
    End If

'================================================================================
' If printer window detected, handle window
'================================================================================

    WScript.Sleep 500

    ret = WshShell.AppActivate(sApp)

    '########This is the top of the endless loop####################
    If ret = True Then
        ret = wshShell.AppActivate(sApp)
        ' Send filename
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        wshShell.sendKeys sFileName
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        ' Send file path to save to
        wshShell.sendKeys "{F4}"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        wshShell.sendKeys "{BS}"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        wshShell.sendKeys "^A"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        wshShell.sendKeys "{del}"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        wshShell.sendKeys "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\closeDialogue.vbs"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        ' "Click" print to complete the dialogue window
        wshShell.sendKeys "{enter}"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        wshShell.sendKeys "{enter}"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 500
    '########This is the bottom of the endless loop####################

    WScript.Quit
End Sub

Call handlePrintDial()
```

**Here is the window I am trying to handle:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I discovered that the sendKeys "{enter}" commands were mysteriously causing the script to execute again (two simultaneous instances of the code running at once, per command line). When I removed Enter keys, the code ran normally without kicking off new instances of the script.

Summary: use sendKeys at your own peril. Specifically, it appears **{enter}** can cause the code to have unusual problems.